# What does @ mean in Laravel Blade templates?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've come across the `@` symbol a couple of times in Blade templates. What does it do in laravel blade? Examples are shown below.

```
@method('DELETE') @CRSF @foreach @endforeach
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### @ in Docblocks

*I know you are asking about Blade, but that isn't in the question and comments are transient. Moreover, other readers might find this looking for what the docblocks `@`s are.*

In a comment beginning with `/**` before a class or function the `@` sign signifies a directive to documentation tools like Doxygen or PHPDoc (I think, I've not used that one).  The common directives there include `@param`, `@return`, `@see`, `@seealso`, `@TODO`, `@link`.  An example would be

```
/**
 * Function to do thing.
 * @param int $foo A variable used in the function for reasons.
 * @return A result of the thing done.
 * @seealso Bar::fubar()
 **/
```

### @ in Blade

As mentioned in other answers the `@` symbol is the prefix for Blade "commands" called directives.  The two you are asking about specifically are built into Laravel.  The ones you're looking at are likely built in, but you can add directives to [make your own](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-blade) for things you do/print often.

### Method

[**`@method('DELETE')`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing) - RESTful standard define request methods PATCH, and DELETE which are not part of the actual HTTP(S) standard.  To emulate these unsupported methods a hidden field is added to forms in Laravel forms to tell the HTTP kernel what the request method is for matching methods for routing purposes.  So `@method('DELETE')` does something like (not exacatly, but you get the idea):

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="method" value="DELETE" />';
```

### CSRF

**[`@csrf`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf)** formerly `@csrf_field` is a command to get a hidden input with the CSRF token.  There is one to get just token, too -- `@csrf_token` -- which is useful for ajax requests.  @csrf does something like (but not exactly):

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="' . {$csrf_token() . '" />';
```

CSRF tokens are "nonce" (numbers used only once) that help to prevent [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)).

In the cached/compiled blade in `storage/framework/views/`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a command that can be "translated" into PHP. `@` is just a symbol, or more a prefix for the blade related keywords.

So the result of this blade:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
  <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
@endforeach
```

would be equal to this plain PHP:

```
foreach($users as $user) {
  echo "<li>{$user->name}</li>";
}
```

Comment: thank you. what would be the result of @method('DELETE) and @crsf

Comment: you can easily use it in a blade template and can check the source code in the browser to see the generated html page. And/Or you can look it up in the docs and read the explanation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#forms

Answer (score 2):

It means that you are using Blade directives. These are functions of the Laravel template engine.